# AWS Lambda logging I want to move my logging for AWS Lambda from CloudWatch to Elasticsearch and Kibana, using vector(ECS Task)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to move my logging for AWS Lambda from CloudWatch to Elk, using ECS Task or Vm.All my Lambda functions are in Python.To clarify, I want to get rid of CloudWatch, with no streaming to it at all.
Question: How do i make my AWS lambda to push logs to AWS ECS Task or Vm instead of CloudWatch logs?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda is `serverless` and hence it is not easy to get logs of AWS Lmabda directly and Lambda writes the logs to Cloudwatch. Instead of removing logs from Cloudwatch, it is better to `stream the logs from Cloudwatch to ELK` setup by using an additional Lambda function.

`CloudWatch Logs` has a feature called `Subscriptions` for “Real-time Processing of Log Data” which allows sending log events to a Kinesis Stream, Kinesis Firehose Stream, or a Lambda. It is created on a log group. Each log group contains a number of log streams. For each of our existing Lambdas’ log groups, we create a subscription to send the Logs to the new Lambda which will send the logs to the logstash server.

You can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/bbc-design-engineering/lambda-logs-in-elk-e4d924757249) which explains it in much detail.

Comment: Using cloudwatch logs will increase the cost that's main reason to move from cloud watch. I am looking for a solution for lambda to write the logs directly on Vm or container.